# what is a virtual adapter

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I hear the term virtual adapter from time to time. But not exactly sure what it is. I can't exactly find a good definition online. Is there an exact definition for a virtual adapter. If so, what is it. Or what does it usually mean ?

Comment: In what context? Without context, I would say a virtual adapter is an adapter that is not physical.

Comment: Yea, I would say the same. My first guess was a representation of a physical device in code. But I wanted a more better definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most scenarios, it involves a device driver at the operating system kernel level that pretends to implement a hardware device.  A very common implementation is a driver that supports VPN.  It looks like a regular network adapter to user code.  But it actually transparently transmits packets across the Internet to a local area network far removed.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com